# I need to add basic auth to my sanctum api

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum, insomnia

I'm using laravel sanctum and I add to middleware to my route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {
    Route::post('/sms-log',[SmsLogController::class, 'store'] );
});
```

But insomnia wants me to sign in:
[insomnia_ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEHrl.png)

when I remove middleware from API route working as expected. so how can I add basic auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In insomnia add a header so you don't get redirected to the login route, instead you get a  `"message":" Not authenticated."`

```
Accept: application/json
```